# Node promise error propagation between classes

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im currently in the process of making my code object oriented and have a problem with propagating promise errors between class instances.

Page.js:

```
exports.Page = class {
  constructor(link, limiter){
    this.link = link;
    //limiter is a instance of bottleneck, use it for rate limiting
    this.limiter = limiter;
  }

  setResults(){
    return new Request(this.link, this.limiter).makeRequest()
    .catch(err => {
      //i dont get here
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
}
```

(is called and initiated from another class)

Request.js:

```
exports.Request = class {
  constructor(options, limiter){
    this.options = options;
    this.limiter = limiter;
  }

  makeRequest(){
    return this.limiter.schedule(this.request, this.options)
    .catch(err => {
      //i get here
      throw err;
    });
  }

  request(url){
    return rp("https://httpstat.us/500")
    .catch(err => {
      //i get here
      throw err;
    })
  }
}
```

So my problem is, that the error wont be propagated back to the page.js but instead prints an unhandled rejection error in the console. I've tried running this without limiter.schedule but it doesnt make a difference. Would be great to get some pointers, cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing an error in a catch might not work correctly when the error is thrown inside an asynchronous function. Replacing `throw err;` with `return Promise.reject(err);` should work.

Answer (score 0):

`.catch()` method is being used to handle Promises errors and rejections. It creates a new promise, so when you use `throw` inside it, then you create another unhandled Promise error.

The thing is, you can't trace where exactly error occurred with native JS.
You can use `Promise.longStackTraces` for Bluebird (a library) promises. Or things like zones.

Answer (score -1):

Callbacks passed to Promises do not return values. Period. Full Stop. You pass a callback as the single argument of either a `.then()` or a `.catch()` which, when run, will never return a value or throw a catch-able Error because it has no context to return or error out to.

Comment: .then and .catch always return a promise. So `somePromisereturningfunc().then(function() {...})` returns a promise

Comment: `.then()` and `.catch()` are functions one can call on a Promise. I was referring to usable results to be had by running callbacks passed to Promises.

Comment: Since my answer could be misinterpreted, I’ve updated it to be clearer but the point remains that, in the context of the OP’s problem, one cannot return a result or throw an error from a “promised” callback.

Comment: I think I still misunderstand your point. `function get(url) { return webservice.get(url).then(function(result) { return "THIS IS THE CALLBACK";});` When I call get("..."), it will return a Promise of the result of the callback function. Eventually, when all goes well, this return value will resolve to 'THIS IS THE CALLBACK'

Comment: You are mistaken. Try capturing the result of your function and printing it to the console. Factoring out your `webservice.get()`, try evaluating `const f = () => Promise.resolve().then(() => "this value is inaccessible"); const result = f(); console.log(result)`. You’ll find that `{ }` will be printed on the console. This is because, as I stated in my answer, you cannot return a value or throw an error from a Promised callback because there is no context to which anything might be returned or thrown.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Jelmerjellema/9vmeL5sL/
Show function f returning the result of then(), being a promise, and itself thenable to something else than the first promise result.

Comment: Lol. Ok you just proved my point. Using your example, you cannot access `promiseResult` outside of the callback in which it is wrapped, and so, other than a Promise which can be further chained, you cannot return a value or throw an error from a chain of Promise `.then()’s.

Comment: We are on a different planet. I just showed the return of your example was not {}, as you *promissed*.  As with every function the returns some result - be it a promise or a plain result, one can either propagate the return value in a chain, save the return value or do both. (x = promisefunction()).then() keeps X the promise with it's resolve.